# Wifi on CentOS Minimal 8

Tags: centos, wifi

I am having a very hard time making Wifi work on a Minimal Centos 8 installation. Using `nmtui` I can make Ethernet/Wired work, but I cant make Wifi work. It does not even show up on `nmtui`, only Wired shows up.

Driver is installed correctly, but I think I need to install something else, like `wpa_supplicant` or `iw` or something else. When I install the Centos Full (with everything that comes in the ISO) the Wifi shows up on `nmtui` perfectly.

So, how can I make Wifi work on Minimal Centos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest use iwconfig command by install wireless-tools package with :

```
yum install wireless-tools
```

for more information check

```
man iwconfig
```